# Python Unit Testing checking stdout of a list after while loop

Tags: python, list, unit-testing, while-loop

I tried to word the question right, but what I'm trying to do is check the stdout of a list after the while statement. I mock the user input for two iterations and break during the thirs iteration.

here is my run code.

```
def main():

    pirateList = []
    maxLengthList = 6

    while len(pirateList) < maxLengthList:
        item = input("Argh! Enter the item: ")

        if item == "exit":
            break;
        else:
            pirateList.append(item)
            print(pirateList)


    print(pirateList)


main()
```

here is my test code, i should be expecting `[bow, arrow]`

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import io
import sys
from RunFile import main

class GetInputTest(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch('builtins.input', side_effect=["bow", "arrow","exit"])
  def test_output(self,m):
      saved_stdout = sys.stdout
      try:
          out = io.StringIO()
          sys.stdout = out
          main()
          output = out.getvalue().strip()
          assert output.endswith('[bow, arrow]')
      finally:
          sys.stdout = saved_stdout


if __name__ == "__main__":
   unittest.main()
```

when I run this code the program just gets hung up.No errors or tracks

Comment: This would be easier to test if `main` simply called a function that *returned* `pirate_list` (see [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)): `def main(): pirate_list = create_pirate_list(6); print(pirate_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

The import statement you are having

```
 from RunFile import main
```

Actually runs the main function, as it should, and asks for the input. You should have the standard if-clause there:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

You might also want to change the stdout handling, here is an example:

```
class GetInputTest(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch('builtins.input', side_effect=["bow", "arrow","exit"])
  @patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO)
  def run_test_with_stdout_capture(self , mock_output, mock_input ):
      main()
      return mock_output.getvalue()

  def test( self ):
      print ("GOT: + " + self.run_test_with_stdout_capture())


if __name__ == "__main__":
   unittest.main()
```

Do note that you cannot print inside the @patch sys.stdout -- it will get captured!

Comment: The program still gets hung up on the user input. No Errors or anything. I may take the advice from above by simply returning `PirateList`

Comment: Really? Did you add the "if __name == main" to the RunFile.py ? 

But yes, using function to return the list, and matching to that, is better testing that matching the stdout.